# Carto, CartoCSS : style point by hex value stored in table

Tags: carto, cartocss

I have a table of points.

Each row has a string `hex` field that stores a color code in hex format: `#000000`.

I want to style my map so that each point displays with the color assigned to it.

But setting the CartoCSS `marker-fill` property to `[hex]` throws an error:

```
 #points {
   marker-fill: [hex];
 }
```

Is there any way that I can color my points based on a color field in my table?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `;` at the end of your code. Check the following example:

[image]

[image: sql]

[image: cartocss]

Comment: I have updated my example, which I typed incorrectly. But my production code includes a semicolon, and still throws an error: "style0:3:2 Invalid value for marker-fill, the type color is expected. [hex] (of type field) was given."

Comment: Can you share the link to your dataset? It should work both in Engine apps (as seen in my first screenshot) and in BUILDER (as in the new pictures added to my answer).

Comment: We're running an on-premise enterprise Carto server with private data, so I can't share. But if it helps, we're running Carto 2.0.0 - could it possibly be a version issue?

Comment: I recommend contacting CARTO Enterprise support next time. I think you are right, maybe your BUILDER onpremise version is not having to use expressions in CartoCSS marker properties such as `marker-fill`. So not related to your data. **Disclaimer**: I work in CARTO.